# "nvm ls" doesn't show any installed NodeJs

Tags: nvm

I used nvm to install two version of NodeJs using Ansible.

1) Install NVM:
- name: install nvm
  sudo_user: go
  shell: >
      curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.1/install.sh | bash

- name: change permission for nvm installation dir
  sudo_user: go
  command: bash -c 'chmod -R 777 ~/.nvm '

2) Install NodeJS 5.5.0 and 0.12.7
- name: install node v5.5.0
  sudo_user: go
  command: bash -c '. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm install v5.5.0/0.12.7 '
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://17.99.193.229:3128
    https_proxy: http://17.99.193.229:3128

3) I didn't get any errors.
4) When I type "node -v", I got v5.5.0.
5) When I use "nvm ls" using "go" as user, I got:
mkdir: cannot create directory `~': Permission denied
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)

As you can see, I use sudo_user go for all the installtion, but I don't see the node I installed.

Answer (score 0):

nvm maintainer here - never use `sudo` with `nvm`. nvm is per-user; and each user account needs its own independent installation of nvm and $NVM_DIR.